# No puedo crear un package

Tags: oracle

Intento crear un paquete PL/SQL en Oracle con la cabecera

```
create  PACKAGE "PO_LDS_CLI_AFECTADO2"  AS
PROCEDURE GET_VIP(V_ORDER in number, v_out OUT NUMBER);
END po_lds_cli_afectado2;
```

y el cuerpo

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY           "PO_LDS_CLI_AFECTADO2"     AS
PROCEDURE GET_VIP(v_order IN NUMBER, v_out OUT NUMBER)
IS
v_rpta  INTEGER;
BEGIN
    v_rpta := PO_LDS_SYNCIFX.GET_CLIENTE_IMPORTANTE_AFEC(v_order);   
  v_out := v_rpta;      
END GET_VIP
END po_lds_cli_afectado2

drop package po_lds_cli_afectado2
```

Pero obtengo el siguiente error:

```
pls-00103 Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when excepting one of the following: ;
```

Comment: Es posible que te falte el `;` al final de cada instrucción; en tu caso, al final de: `po_lds_cli_afectado2`.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te faltan varios ; en tu código (en el body):

```
    create or replace PACKAGE BODY           "PO_LDS_CLI_AFECTADO2"     AS
        PROCEDURE GET_VIP(v_order IN NUMBER, v_out OUT NUMBER) IS
            v_rpta  INTEGER;
        BEGIN
            v_rpta := PO_LDS_SYNCIFX.GET_CLIENTE_IMPORTANTE_AFEC(v_order);   
            v_out := v_rpta;      
        END GET_VIP;
   END po_lds_cli_afectado2;
```

Comment: he intendado pero igual me sale error. Usé la misma documentación de **Oracle** para crear el package https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6007.htm y nada me sale otro error *Error: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "/" The symbol "/" was ignored*.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta con el código actualizado, por favor

Comment: Si era eso simplemente faltaban punto y comas